# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError on adding element in arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist, out-of-memory

Reading file names from the device and add them into ArrayList for handling the same files name but add method of ArrayList throwing exception.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 55380616 byte allocation with 25165824 free bytes and 25MB until OOM, max allowed footprint 534834552, growth limit 536870912
       at java.util.Arrays.copyOf + 3139(Arrays.java:3139)
       at java.util.Arrays.copyOf + 3109(Arrays.java:3109)
       at java.util.ArrayList.grow + 275(ArrayList.java:275)
       at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity + 249(ArrayList.java:249)
       at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal + 241(ArrayList.java:241)
       at java.util.ArrayList.add + 467(ArrayList.java:467)
```

```java
    private static void loadFile(File s){
        try {
            if (!canAddTheseFiles(s)){
                return;
            }
            File myDirectoryFiles[] = s.listFiles();
            for (int i = 0; currentDirectoryFiles != null && i<myDirectoryFiles.length; i++){
                if (myDirectoryFiles[i].isFile()){
                    currentDirectoryFiles.add(myDirectoryFiles[i].getName());
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            // if any error occurs
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static boolean canAddTheseFiles(File file){
        return file.isDirectory() && file.canRead();
    }
```

Comment: It seems that you're adding so many names to the list (or doing something somewhere else) that you're exceeding your allocated heap. You'll need to increase it or try using streams.

Comment: use android:largeheap = true in manifest file

Comment: First remove `currentDirectoryFiles != null` from loop .. just check it outside only once . Also provide code how are you calling this method and method `canAddTheseFiles`.. There is no way a ArrayList with name can fill upto `55380616 bytes` ..

Comment: @JawadAhmed ** largeheap = true** already added in manifest

Comment: @ADM I only called this method if that specify directory already not read. Second, whenever I create a new file, I also add that name in this ArrayList and same exception also throwing on that line. `canAddTheseFiles` method added

Comment: I disagree with adding `largeheap=true` in the manifest file. There's straight up no way the ArrayList would be this big from only names

Comment: `s.listFiles()` causes memory overhead too; though the directory path should then be long, and there should be many files. More suspicious might be that `currentDirectoryFiles.clear()` is what I would have expected before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to run out of memory doing something like you are doing - you should consider trying to load only a subset of the list as you use it.

The problem I see above though is a misunderstanding of how an ArrayList functions - as it grows you are using double the memory you think you are (temporarily):

Using `new ArrayList()` is making `new String[10]`. So the first ten items you add go directly into that backing array. Now what happens when you reach the 11th item is the ArrayList grows itself - as shown in your StackTrace.

It can't do that by just expanding an array - instead it creates a brand new array, twice as big and copies everything across. So suddenly you have `new String[10] + new String[20]` for a while. Once you reach the twentieth item, it doubles it again (and so on)

If you have thousands of items at some point you can end up with (for example) `new String[20000] + new String[40000]` while it copies across

If you know how many items are in your list already you can make the list big enough to start with.

For example if you think you will reach 2345 items, then you could start with

```
new ArrayList(2400);
```

Now it won't do any growing and you only have to worry there is enough space for all your actual strings

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I resolved it by another way.

Comment: Then you should post your answer here for future users, it's fine to answer your own question. Why did you downvote ?

Answer (score -2):

Every time you are in the for loop you add a new element to your list.This file names' size you have been keeping in the list is something like takes more than heap size for all file names, thats why you keep adding elements until the heap space runs out.

Answer (score -2):

ArrayList contains array under the hood. Array == continuous (without holes) chunk of memory. It is almost not possible to acquire it, when it comes very big (reason for *Failed to allocate...*). You can try LinkedList in such case.